# Redshift Unload to S3 Location that is a Concatenated String

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload the results from a redshift query to a bucket folder that is yesterday's date.

So in the below example the data should be in s3://mybucket/reporting/20170321/myreport-000

```
unload ('select * from #my_report')
to 's3://mybucket/reporting/' || replace(trunc(current_date - 1),'-','') || '/myreport'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=key;aws_secret_access_key=secretkey'
delimiter ','
gzip addquotes null as ''
PARALLEL off
allowoverwrite;
```

However I get the error

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "||";
```

Does the string concatenation not evaluate first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to dynamically build the `UNLOAD` path statement.

Two methods I can suggest:

- **Method 1:** I would suggest writing a shell script/Python/Javascript where you can create variables, then pass in those variables into a connection's statement-query.
- **Method 2:** Or you can use `RedshiftCopyActivity` in [AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html) to copy from Redshift to S3. Input is RedshiftDataNode and output is S3DataNode where you can specify expression for directoryPath.

  If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Could it be done with PREPARE/EXECUTE? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html

Comment: @systemjack - From what I know, No. It cannot be done with PREPARE/EXECUTE command. An EXECUTE command has to be issued for the prepared statement which is again same as the above question.